# Gravity Forms gform_after_submission not working in cutom plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a plugin and trying to call **gforms_after_submission hook** within the plugin. For some reason it isn't calling the function. I am using this **gforms_after_submission hook** because I want to create a custom post on gravity form submit.

There are some plugins which create custom post on gravity form submit, but I want to do it with custom code.

Please help me..

Comment: Are you adding the hook on plugins loaded? Perhaps check when they execute the action in their plugin and make sure your hook is added before that.

Comment: Ok Please let me give it a try...

Comment: Thanks Man #MirzaP# it solved my issue....

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the answer here as well. Make sure your hook is added before their plugin's hook is executed by do_action in order for your hook to be picked up.